# Can I make an asynchronous javascript method behave synchronously with async-waterfall?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have three function calls in my JavaScript application, and the second one is asynchronous, so it looks something like this.

```
function runner() {
    function1();
    function2(); //This is the one that is asynchronous
    function3();
}
```

This results in a problem where function3 has finished before function2 has, resulting in problems for my application. So far my application is in pure javascript, but I am looking for a robust way to ensure that my functions run sequentially without having to go into callback hell. I thought that I could maybe us [async-waterfall](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-waterfall), but I am not running node on my application, I am just in the browser. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: If your `function2` neither accepts a callback nor returns a promise object then there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Well, that's not strictly true. He could lock up the browser waiting for some side-effect of `function2` via an infinite loop. But I'd also suggest promises.

Comment: No, he can't. Because this side-effect would have to be triggered by a parallel process which cannot run since js is single threaded. An infinite loop simply kills the page.

Comment: What is the "async-waterfall" mentioned in the title? I see no reference to that in the question.

Comment: @NickP What is the environment that you're running in? Browser or Node.js?

Comment: I am running all of this in the browser, so I am not using node.js. Yes, the async-waterfall is node.js, but could I use just that one function?

Comment: `async.waterfall()` is a function of an external Javascript package. It doesn't have anything to do with Node, you can depend upon it in any Javascript environment.

Comment: So would I then need to just download that?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely cannot modify your functions to utilize promises or accept callbacks, one solution is to use an `interval` to check if `function2` is done. Definitely not the best approach, but something like this would work.

I'd argue this is a bit worse than callback hell though.

```
var waitFor = function(test, success) {
  var iv = setInterval(function() { 
  if (test()) { 
    clearInterval(iv); 
    success();
  }, 500);
}

var isFunction2Done = function() {
  //some logic here, true if done, false otherwise
}

function1();
function2();
waitFor(isFunction2Done, function3);
```